# VBA: Union function not working to delete non-contiguous columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Using the UNION function, the code below should **delete the entire column for specified cols B, D & F.**

I choose UNION function because several SE posts suggested UNION FUNCTION as most efficient method of selecting non-contiguous cols.

I thought by defining the range through "SET" I had properly declared the specific columns to delete.

The code runs without error on worksheet with data in rows "A" thru "M" but deletes no columns.

Thanks for taking time to assist me!

```
    Sub Union_Function_del_NonContig_Cols()


Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim R1, R2, R3, R4 As Range

  Set R1 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
  Set R2 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("D:D")
  Set R3 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("F:F")

Range("R1:R3").EntireColumn.Delete

 End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you using the union function? Range("R1:R3") has nothing to do with your range variables, it is three cells - R1, R2, and R3.

Comment: `Union(R1,R2,R3).EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: T.J.L - being a VBA newby, I thought that by Dimming and the Setting the 4 Ranges (R1, R2, R3, R4) that I could then (in 2nd to last line) use those DIM'd / SET variables in the RANGE.

Comment: Brilliant simplicity, Scott Craner! Many thanks! BTW, is UNION the most efficient method of deleting non-contiguous columns when the cols to be deleted are always the same?

Comment: `Range("B:B, D:D, F:F").EntireColumn.Delete` is pretty much the same but removed a few steps. btw, `Range("B:B", "D:D", "F:F").EntireColumn.Delete` is **not** the same.

Comment: Jeep, what is the diff between Range("B:B, D:D, F:F").EntireColumn.Delete vs Range("B:B", "D:D", "F:F").EntireColumn.Delete? 2nd q: Is there any efficiency gained by dispensing with UNION Function in favor of the solution you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your code needs little correction and you can use following VBA code to delete multiple columns.*

```
Sub Union_Function_del_NonContig_Cols()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngUnion As Range

Set rng1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
Set rng2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")

Set rngUnion = Union(rng1, rng2)
rngUnion.Columns.Delete

End Sub
```

**N.B.** *In above code Sheet & Column name are editable.*

Comment: Brilliant solution, Mr. Rajesh! Is the UNION function your preferred method for deleting non-contiguous columns? Many thanks!

Comment: PS Sorry I don't have rep pts. to upvote both you and Scott Carney!

Comment: @WyoWindStorm,, it's okay But you can accept it as an ANSWER,, [Check this](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: Green check mark - done! I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @WyoWindStorm,, glad to help you keep asking ☺